# Cycling Stop Animation by Clicking (Issue)

Tags: javascript, animation

The issue i am having has to do with the animation freezing when the user clicks on the last frame of the animation. I have made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vh9mgwk8/). Click when the animation is on its last frame and it will freeze. I have tried something to block the input like this when the user clicks.

```
if(active === false){
   active = true;
}
```

but to no avail. It could be something simple i just have no clue.

Comment: What you want to do ??? explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this-

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var activeIMG;
var active = false;
var frame = 7;
window.images = {
    c0: new Image(),
    c1: new Image(),
    c2: new Image(),
    c3: new Image(),
    c4: new Image(),
    c5: new Image(),
    c6: new Image()
};
images.c0.src = 'http://i.imgur.com/Tw3iDG6.png'; //Normal
images.c1.src = 'http://i.imgur.com/nFS1YYw.png'; //Start
images.c2.src = 'http://i.imgur.com/f8BYubj.png'; //Boom
images.c3.src = 'http://i.imgur.com/96N0hLn.png'; //Boom Smoke
images.c4.src = 'http://i.imgur.com/1iACNo8.png'; //Thick Smoke
images.c5.src = 'http://i.imgur.com/eZxuXtC.png'; //Lighter Smoke
images.c6.src = 'http://i.imgur.com/ooZJYa9.png'; //Rounding Smoke
activeIMG = images.c0;

$('body').mousedown(function (event) {
    var chords = ("X: " + event.pageX + "Y: " + event.pageY);
    if (frame > 6) {
        active = true;
        frame = 0;
    }
});
setInterval(function change() {
    if (active) {
        activeIMG = window.images["c" + frame++];
        //console.log(activeIMG)
        active= frame <= 6;
    } else {
        activeIMG = window.images["c0"];
    }       
}, 150);

    function draw() {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
        ctx.drawImage(activeIMG, 0, 0);

        requestAnimationFrame(draw);
    }
    draw();
```

Here's the demo http://jsfiddle.net/vikrant47/vh9mgwk8/2/

Comment: Wow, thanks that's a way better way to cycle through the images.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting `active` to `false` as soon as you hit frame 6, so it is now "restartable", you want to set it when frame 6 has been drawn / or frame 7 (repeat frame 1) starts.

Set a breakpoint on case 6 and step through it.

Comment: Ahh Thanks feels soo good. all i needed to do was make another case and then have that set the frames back to zero.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i make this possible, Look i have made some changes in your code:

```
var test = function(event){
    var chords = ("X: " + event.pageX + "Y: " + event.pageY);
    //alert(chords);
    active = true;
};

$('body').bind('click',test);//binding click event

$('body').unbind('click');//unbinding it when animation is going on for preventing unwanted click
/* made some changes in case 6 also, binding click event once more and set frame to 0 */
case 6:
     activeIMG = images.c6;
     active = false;
     frame=0;//most important to make frame from start again
     $('body').bind('click',test);//binding again
     break;
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/acz3fe1y/)